# Count tweets and retweets per day using aggregation frameworks

Tags: mongodb, twitter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to count the number of retweets and tweets per day using aggregation frameworks in mongo, but I am having a problem. I can do it separetely, but when I tried to do it only using a query I am not getting any result.

I used the next aggregation framework to get the number of retweets per day

```
    db.tweets.aggregate(
   [
    { $match: { "retweeted_status.id": {"$exists":true} }}
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { 
                day2: { $dayOfMonth: "$created_ts"}, 
                month2 : {$month : "$created_ts" },
                year2: { $year: "$created_ts" },
                },
           totalReTweetsPerDay: { $sum: 1 },
         }
     },
        { $match: { "retweeted_status.id": {"$exists":true} }}
   ]
)
```

And I using the next code to get the number of tweets per day

```
   db.tweets.aggregate(
       [
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: { 
                    day: { $dayOfMonth: "$created_ts"}, 
                    month : {$month : "$created_ts" },
                    year: { $year: "$created_ts" },
                    },
               totalReTweetsPerDay: { $sum: 1 },


  }
     },
     {$sort : { _id : -1}},
     {$out : "daily_tweets" }
   ]
)
```

I would like to join these two operations in one. I tried to join it only copyng one inside the other but it is not working.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What is your MongoDB server version?

Comment: I have the version 3.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. The only thing to note is the inclusion for `ifNull` operator which checks for existence of field.

```
db.tweets.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                day: {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$created_ts"
                },
                month: {
                    $month: "$created_ts"
                },
                year: {
                    $year: "$created_ts"
                },
            },
            totalReTweetsPerDay: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [{
                        $ifNull: ["$retweeted_status.id", false]
                    }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            totalTweetsPerDay: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            _id: -1
        }
    }, {
        $out: "daily_tweets"
    }]
)
```

Comment: Hi, it is not working, it creates the collection but it is null. My mongo version is 3.2.4

Comment: Can you verify and see what you get if you leave `{
        $out: "daily_tweets"
    }`  out?

Comment: I am not getting anything. It does not show any error, but I am not getting any result

Comment: Sorry the collection name should be `tweets` not `tweet`. Fixed the answer.  Please try again.